# Could you tell me why I need "the" here?

Tags: grammar, definite-article

> I think that **the/no article** means of transport will become even more accessible in
>   the future, which will tempt more people to travel.

The grammar rules I know suggest **NOT** to put "the" here because it is a general context, but a native English speaker, lots of newspapers and my gut tell me to put "the" for some reason.  I need to know this reason to not repeat this mistake (if it is a mistake) again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definite article is used when you are talking about one or more **specific** things:

> I put **the** book that you gave to me last week
>   I took **the** books to the charity shop yesterday

An indefinite article is used when you are talking about one **non-specific** thing:

> I need **a** book to take on holiday with me

No article is required if you are talking about more than one **non-specific** thing:

> I like reading books

---

If you are talking about a specific means of transport, you use the definite article:

> While **the means of transport** is sometimes the attraction itself... - [Tourist management in South Africa](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=kmJPwmorZFcC&pg=PA128&dq=%22the%20means%20of%20transport%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIgc3MhdvoAhVbfSsKHVuvC2MQ6AEIVTAF#v=onepage&q=%22the%20means%20of%20transport%22&f=false)

When talking about means of transport in general, you are talking about many different sorts of transport, so you do not use any article:

> Some means of transport spread slowly, others rapidly, and some are never adopted in particular areas [Improving rural mobility](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=BID5BS_8xdwC&pg=PA22&dq=%22means%20of%20transport%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxnKr7htvoAhVYWX0KHSjlDvMQ6AEIbDAI#v=onepage&q=%22means%20of%20transport%22&f=false)